# Magnolia - child component, or area that always contains 1 child component of a specific class

Tags: java, thymeleaf, magnolia

In a Magnolia/Blossom component, is it possible to define and render a child component of another type (or an [Area](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/modules/magnolia-module-blossom/2.0/magnolia-module-blossom/apidocs/info/magnolia/module/blossom/annotation/Area.html) that is defined to always contain exactly one component of a specific type, is prepopulated and has a clean author interface)?

e.g. I have a rich text component. I want to build another component that has an section within it that uses this rich text component. I could create an Area that has a maximum of 1 child components, and only allows this component type, but that would require the author to manually add it each time - plus the author interface is ugly*.

FWIW I'm using Magnolia 5.4.9, the Blossom module 3.1.3 and Thymeleaf 2.1.4.

*I have the following but this is what I'm trying to avoid - it contains 2 wrappers for a single component, plus a redundant 'maximum number of components reached' area
[image: Magnolia - Redundant author interface elements]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having editor to create instance of the component manually, you can use [autogeneration](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS45/Template+prototype#Templateprototype-Autogeneratedcomponents).

To get rid of green bars in UI ... apart from writing all yourself inside of single component, you can try to examine element IDs to see if you can custom tweak CSS to hide it, but like it will not be possible.